# why this question get closed on SU which is related to gmail?

Tags: support, closed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Superuser website applications policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39615/superuser-website-applications-policy)

https://superuser.com/questions/127516/web-cam-symbol-in-gmail-chat-window-closed

This is the reason showing

> closed as off-topic by heavyd, random♦
>   5 hours ago   Questions on Super User
>   are expected to generally relate to
>   computer software or computer hardware
>   in some way, within the scope defined
>   in the faq.

on Super User

> are expected to generally relate to
>   computer software or computer hardware
>   in some way

is it means , internet, gmail etc are not comes under Computer software according to SU?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39615/superuser-website-applications-policy

Answer (score 3):

This issue (and similar issues) has been heavily and thoroughly debated on Meta.  It has resulted in changes to the [faq](https://superuser.com/faq):

> and it is not about …
>       * videogames or consoles
>       * websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
>       * electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer

You may have looked at an old version of the faq somehow, before that was there.  Gmail is generally considered to fall under that second bullet point.

Comment: and what about mail services?

Comment: It's a mail service, but it's also a website.

Comment: ok it means Outlook questions allowed but gmail not. but these day more and more application are going on browsers.

Comment: Having read a number of your questions on SO, SU and Meta, I strongly recommend that you take some time and read the comprehensive FAQ thoroughly, to catch issues that have already been addressed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Comment: Hmm.  You posted exactly the same thing as me.  -1.  But you used an image with freehand circles.  +1.  End result, you just get this comment.

Comment: Don't forget the freehand circles are *floating*.